# How do I configure a Kubernetes Ingress to rewrite an API response?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm running an application in Kubernetes that sits behind a **ClusterIP** service (which is then accessed from the outside world via an **Ingress** policy).

The hosted application offers an API, which is accessed from the outside world via the Ingress service - e.g.

```
example.com/api/my_ip
```

And responds with the IP address of the **Pod** the application lives in. This API value is used for other services to access the application on `example.com` so an ephemeral, private, Pod IP is of little use.

I know it is possible with an Kubernetes Nginx Ingress to create URL rewrite annotations, but these seem to only rewrite a given URL. Does an annotation (or another solution) exist that will rewrite the JSON response from this API from, e.g.

```
{"LocalAddress":"http://10.88.160.78:1234"}
```

to

```
{"LocalAddress":"http://example.com:1234"}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this API? To what use would it be to know the port which the pod is listening inside the cluster? Because it's not accessible from outside with the given port. All traffic that exits the cluster usually is generated by the pod itself. Please take a look at [**how to create a minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide as much information as possible, so the community can help you better

Comment: The purpose of the hosted API to to allow a Chromecast to learn what machine it needs to connect to, to pull media content.

Currently the API reports its Pod IP, when really it should be a FQDN. The Chromecast will not be able to access the Pod IP, but will be able to access via the Ingress. If the API will report an "incorrect" IP, I would like to rewrite its response somehow...

Comment: Have you consider stable network identifiers like Statefulsets or pods with [hostname and subdomain fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods-hostname-and-subdomain-fields)?